# Are there better ways to say "I like the sentence someone said" or "I love this sentence someone said"?

Tags: phrase-request, colloquial-language

If I hear someone（esp. a very famous person) say something (e.g. a sentence) and I appreciate that sentence very much, what can I say?

"I like the sentence someone said" or "I love this sentence someone said" sounds awkward to me.

Comment: Perhaps "I like the sentence that I heard". Someone *said* it but you *heard* it. There is no reason to add someone if you don't know who it was.

Comment: Your statement is certainly grammatical, but "the sentence" is not natural. You are right to call it awkward, for its register is rather analytical and yet the gist of your sentence is that you *like* what was said.  A native speaker, speaking casually, might say "I like what he said" or "I like that turn of phrase" or "I like his way with words".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine, depending on context you might want to add "about"

> I like **the** sentence *someone* said *(about)*...
>   I love **this** sentence someone said *(about)*...

If you use **this** usually you might quote the actual sentence you like.

> I like **the** sentence President Kennedy said about going to the moon.
>
> I love **this** sentence President Kennedy said: "Ask not what your country can do for you, ask what you can do for your country."